# Redirecting customers to custom page after sale in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to learn WooCommerce and WordPress plugins so I'm tweaking around. I'm trying to create a plugin that redirects customer to a custom page after checkout. The custom page/url can be defined when I create the product. Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Redirect After Sale
Description: Redirects customers to a custom page after a successful sale.
*/

// Register a new meta field for products
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'custom_redirect_meta_box' );
function custom_redirect_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'custom_redirect_meta_box', 'Custom Redirect URL', 'custom_redirect_meta_box_callback', 'product', 'side' );
}
function custom_redirect_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_redirect_url', true );
    echo '<label for="custom_redirect_url">Custom Redirect URL:</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="custom_redirect_url" name="custom_redirect_url" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" style="width:100%">';
}

// Save the meta field value when the product is saved
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'save_custom_redirect_meta_box_data' );
function save_custom_redirect_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['custom_redirect_url'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_redirect_url', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_redirect_url'] ) );
    }
}

// Redirect to the custom page after a successful sale
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_redirect_after_sale' );

function custom_redirect_after_sale( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    //$order->update_status( 'completed' );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    // Get the first product in the order
    $product = reset($items);

    // Get the custom redirect URL for the product
    //$redirect_url = get_post_meta( $product->get_product_id(), '_custom_redirect_url', true );
    $redirect_url = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_custom_redirect_url', true );
    //echo "Meta retrieved: " . $redirect_url;
    
    //error_log("callback fired");

    //echo "Payment complete ho ho ho";

    if( $redirect_url ) {
        wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

It seems the `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook is not firing. I tried to echo out the redirect url and text but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm on localhost and I'm using the cash on delivery payment method.

Comment: I posted an answer, if you have any questions let me know

Answer (score 0):

Basing this answer on the great https://rudrastyh.com/ - specifically this tutorial https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/thank-you-page.html#redirects this is the code that should work for what you are trying to do.

1. First, you hook into the template_redirect action to determine the URL where the customer needs to go
2. Getting the Order ID, you can get the products purchased for that order
3. Once you have the purchased products, you can get their ID and meta data, the redirect URL you saved for each. Note that while you use WP functions for handling meta, when working with WooCommerce it is best practice to use its CRUD methods. In case in the future they port products to custom tables, your code will continue working.
4. Implement the redirect with the WP function [wp_safe_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/)

Note that what you are trying to achieve will have problems if customers purchase orders with more than 1 product, and you have more than 1 redirect URL. In this implementation, the first product in the order that has a saved redirect URL will override all others

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'purchased_product_redirect');

function purchased_product_redirect(){
    if( !function_exists( 'is_wc_endpoint_url' )){
       return;
    }
    // do nothing if we are not on the order received page
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) || empty( $_GET[ 'key' ] ) ) {
        return; 
    }
        
    // Get the order ID
    $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key( $_GET[ 'key' ] );
    
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
   
    // Get and Loop Over Order Items
   foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        if(!$product){
          continue;
        }
        //Get the first product's redirect URL
        $product_redirect_url = $product->get_meta('_custom_redirect_url');
        if(!$product_redirect_url){
          continue;
        }
        wp_safe_redirect( $product_redirect_url );
        exit; // always exit after using wp_safe_redirect
    }

}
```